# what is the difference between value and pointcut attributes in advices of spring aop

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

In advice methods of types Afterreturning and Afterthrowing, there are value and pointcut attributes available. When I tried some hands on, found that both are replaceable with each other and if both present, pointcut takes precedence over value. Can someone please throw a light on difference between these two attributes in context of spring AOP advices.

Comment: afterreturn activates after return statement, and afterthrowing activates after throw statement. duh. If it doesn't work like that, try to update your dependencies

Comment: @Sarief, this has nothing to do with what he asked

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between the two. If both are defined, `pointcut` takes precedence. Also, if only the `value` attribute is present, the keyword can me omitted allowing use of `@AfterThrowing("com.something.something.something")` instead of `@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "com.something.something.something")` which simplifies the expression.